# trying to list projects in google cloud shell and getting error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-api-python-client

I am trying to list projects which are available to my account through the following python code from cloudshell terminal

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials as creds
crm = discovery.build(
    'cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

filter = "name:project a"
projects = crm.projects().list(filter=filter).execute()
```

but after the execution of the following line, i m getting this error:

```
crm = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(httplib2.Http()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method authorize() must be called with OAuth2Credentials instance as first argument (got Http instance instead)
```

I am new to google cloud and python, Kindly help thanks

Comment: You need to first authorize using service account or `OAuth2Credentials`

Answer (score 1):

```
from google.cloud import resource_manager
   
client = resource_manager.Client()
for project in client.list_projects():
    print(project)
```

This should give all projects in the current context set by the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`